# Strange behavior using lsof and awk together in Mac terminal?

Tags: regex, macos, awk, lsof

I want to find all of the lines in `lsof` with "Google" in them, so I tried the following:

```
lsof |  awk '/.*google.*/ { print $1 "," $2 "," $3} ' > new_file.csv
```

which yields correctly an output with rows starting with the word "google".

But, then I try this and the csv contains nothing:

```
lsof |  awk '/\s*google.*/ { print $1 "," $2 "," $3} ' > new_file.csv
```

But, I thought that the `\s*` means any number of spaces.  Is there any reason for this behavior?  Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\s` does mean spaces and `\s*` does mean zero-or-more spaces but not in awk.

awk uses a different (older) regex engine.

For awk you want `[[:space:]]*` to match zero-or-more spaces. (That's a character class class of `[:space:]` in a character list `[]`.)

That being said if you just care about `google` being in the output then you just need `/google/`.

If you want an word-anchored `google` then you want `/\<google\>/`.

As Ed Morton points out GNU Awk version 4.0+ added support for the `\s` metacharacter as well.

Comment: `\s` does mean any space char in GNU awk.

Comment: I tried `lsof | gawk '/^\s*oogle/ { print $1 ", " $2 }'`  but it still returns nothing.  I looked at the man pages for `gawk` and it says that the `^` means "beginning of string".

Comment: What version of gawk? Do you actually care about the leading spaces? Does the line with "google" in it really start with spaces? `/^\s*oogle/` will *not* match a line with "google" in it. It will match a line that starts with zero-or-more spaces and then contains "oogle" immediately after that.

Comment: gawk versioin 4.1.3.  The leading spaces are because I want this to run on both mac temrinal and  cygwn.  Cygwin sometimes puts weird spaces before lines of  output (for example, in netstat they put spaces before the output).  Plus, I'd like to understand why it doesn't work, for long term benefit.

Comment: If your pattern doesn't look for spaces then it doesn't care about spaces. The pattern `/google/` will match *any* line that contains "google" in it *anywhere* spaces or not. Don't over-specify your match. If all you want is a line that says "google" on it *somewhere* use `/google/` or `/\<google\>/` if you want "google" as a word by itself. Just as I explained in the answer itself.